# Number of connections keep on increasing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset, mongodb-atlas

I am using mongodb and setup it mongodb atlas. I have used `mongoose` to establish connection between database and nodejs.

Now the problem is my number of connection is being increased thoroughly.

Here is mongoose connection request

```
const mongooseOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoReconnect: true,
  poolSize: 25,
  connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000
} 

exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  defaults = Hoek.applyToDefaults(defaults, options)

  if (Mongoose.connection.readyState) {
    return next()
  }

  if (!Mongoose.connection.readyState) {
    server.log(`${process.env.NOED_ENV} server connecting to ${defaults.url} ${defaults.url}`)

    return Mongoose.connect(defaults.url, mongooseOptions).then(() => {
      return next() // call the next item in hapi bootstrap
    })
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in the configuration. Kindly help

Comment: how do you know that the number of connections kept increasing?

Comment: I can check the graph on the Atlas analytics